# Parser error in declaring data variable in google colab in python language

Tags: python, parsing, variables, google-colaboratory

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/sop/Sheet1.csv", encoding="latin1", delimiter=' ')
```

In this code snippet when declaring the data variable i am getting the following error

```
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 7, saw `
```

there is some error in the encoding or delimter part of the code